# Aggregate data by last n days for each row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in below format -

```
Date        Amount
1/1/2000       1
2/1/2000       1    
3/1/2000       1
4/1/2000       2
5/1/2000       1
6/1/2000       1
7/1/2000       1
```

Here, each row represents Amount collected on that day, I want to prepare a table where each row represents amount collected on last 3 days. Thus for 3/1/2000 - it will show amount =3 ( Amount 1 on 1/1 , 1 on 2/1 and 1 on 3/1 , so 1+1+1 = 3

So, from above data, table I want is -

```
Date        Amount
1/1/2000       1    //1
2/1/2000       2    //1+1    
3/1/2000       3    //1+1+1
4/1/2000       4    //1+1+2
5/1/2000       4    //1+2+1
6/1/2000       4    //2+1+1
7/1/2000       3    //1+1+1
```

How to write a SQL query for this?

I tried this -

```
select date, sum(amount) as amount_sum
from SQLTABLE
where DATEDIFF(date,date)<=2 
group by date
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (The answer will probably be product specific.)

Comment: I am using MySQL database.

Comment: I tried this - 
select date, sum(amount) as amount_sum
from SQLTABLE
where DATEDIFF(date,date)<=2 
group by date

Comment: Can you try this:i am not sure about mysql    select date,
    (select sum(amount) from yourtable t2 where t2.date>=t1.date) summ
    from 
    yourtable t1

Comment: @TheGameiswar on using the above code, join is not working ---
Error: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

Join works if changing t2.date >= t1.date to t2.date=t1.date , but that wouldn't give desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subqueries in order to get the `Amount` values of the two previous records:

```
SELECT `Date`, 
       Amount + 
       COALESCE((SELECT Amount 
                 FROM mytable AS t2
                 WHERE t2.`Date` < t1.`Date`
                 ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1), 0) +
       COALESCE((SELECT Amount 
                 FROM mytable AS t2
                 WHERE t2.`Date` < t1.`Date`
                 ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1, 1), 0) AS Amount
FROM mytable AS t1
```

The above query works even if there are *gaps* between consecutive records.

**Edit:**

If there are *no gaps* between consecutive records, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT `Date`,       
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Amount)
                 FROM mytable AS t2
                 WHERE t2.date <= t1.date AND DATEDIFF(t1.date,t2.date) <= 2
                 ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1), 0) AS Amount
FROM mytable AS t1
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work, but a more generic way would be to aggregate SUM based on where clause. With your approach, doing it for n days would be too much code. 
For aggregating over n days -

SELECT date, (SELECT sum(amount) from SQLTABLE t2 WHERE DATEDIFF(t1.date,t2.date) IN (0,1,2)) amount_sum 
from SQLTABLE t1

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using a sub-select.

```
SELECT date, 
       (SELECT sum(amount) 
       from SQLTABLE t2 
       WHERE DATEDIFF(t1.date,t2.date) IN (0,1,2)) amount_sum 
from SQLTABLE t1
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution create `n` subqueries where n is the number of rows. I have a table to 9 million rows where I need to find last 7 days for each row, but 9 million subqueries seem to really bad for my DB. Any ideas/suggestions?